# How to extract contour lines from a surface plot in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, charts

I have several surface plots.  I would like to combine one contour line from each plot into a single plot.  Is there a way to extract the contour line that excel generates?

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! I believe there is no way to do this directly from the charts.  You would have to extract the contours by direct analysis of the underlying data.  I'll wait a bit to see if someone knows a way, but then convert this comment to an answer if not.

Comment: I recall seeing some software that does this, although I've never used it.  Don't remember if it was described in posts on Super User.  Do some Googling.  If I stumble back across it, I'll post back.